# Gitlab CI does not execute npm scripts

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, npm-install, npm-scripts

I try to make a CI script running on a gitlab runner.

What I want is simple:

First the npm install command should be executed to fetch all the required npm packages.

After that the `npm test` and `npm run build` should be executed.

The `.gitblab-ci.yml` script looks as follow:

```
before_script:
  - cd my/folder/
  - npm install --silent

stages:
  - test
  - build

run_tests:
  script:
    - npm test
  stage: test

build:
  script:
    - npm run build
  stage: build
```

Unfortunatly only the `npm install` gets executed twice. And this not silent.
`npm test` and `npm run build` get never called.

Can anyone tell me, what I do wrong?

Comment: Regarding npm being too verbose, I think the npm maintainers are working on that (see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10732 and https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/15914). Using the --silent option makes it less verbose than without. As for your jobs not running properly, I don't see any obvious mistakes, my npm pipeline looks roughly similar and it works

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem:

```
setup:                                                                                          
    stage: setup
    script:
        - npm install
        - echo "done"
```

But `echo "done"` was never executed. Solution was to add `call` before `npm`:

```
setup:                                                                                          
    stage: setup
    script:
        - call npm install
        - echo "done"
```

[Here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2730) are details. Apparently it has something to do how windows execute batch in batch.